# C# resx file not working after changing namespace

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource, resx

I am working on an existing windows form application. I only need to make few modification, during those changes i came across a scenario where i need to rename an existing namespace aswell. Now after renaming that namespace my project is not running. Although it compiles fine but breaks at the following line of code

```
ImageList il = new ImageList();
ImageList = il;            
il.Images.Add((Image)new Bitmap(GetType(), "Images.ImageFileName.png"));//when this line is executed a dialog box appears and says that "there is no source code available for current location"
```

Now since i am new to .net world so i study this problem and figure that it arises due to change in namspace. I also trying renaming the namespace in the Resources.Designer.cs
but it also didn't  solve my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks All.

I find the solution by myself. The purpose of posting solution here is that may be some one else benefit from it.
Infact its a sort of carelessness from my side because i forget to change the value of Property "Default NameSpace" this property contains the old namespace that's why my resource file alwasy point to old namespace

Answer (score 4):

Right click on `Resources.resx`, select `Properties`, find `Custom Tool Namespace`, set the namespace that you need.

Also, why don't you reference your resources in the typed manner like `Resources.ResrouceName`.

Here is a quick tutorial how you can setup your resources so you don't have to cast and think about namespaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I may be too tired at the moment, or did you forget to include the link to the tutorial? :-)

Answer (score 3):

try getting rid of that second line, `ImageList = il;`. what it's doing is replacing a class with an instance of a class. not good.

Answer (score 1):

I have also came across this issue. I had to rename the namespace of my application. After that the designer was ignoring all resources, although they were appearing after building a solution and running the application.

I found that even though I had renamed the namespace, it wasn't replaced in Application Properties under "Default Namespace" textbox. I have changed the old namespace which was still appearing there with the new namepspace and it worked properly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That specific overload of the bitmap constructor combines the namespace of the given type with the string name of the resource and looks for a match in the assembly manifest. So in this case it would be the namespace of your class + `".Images.ImageFileName.png"`. I'm guessing that does not exist. Change the namespace of the Resources.resx by right clicking on it and selecting properties, do a Rebuild and see if it works now.